# gzip compression for a wordpress home page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, compression, pagespeed

Google pagespeed wants me to enable compression for my example.com/
[image]
my site is powered by wordpress so this is a php generated html page
I have enabled compression like so (apache)

```
# Mod Deflate performs data compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|php|xml|jpg|png|gif|svg)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE no-gzip
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

how can I enable for the main page (/)?

Answer (score 0):

On apache you need to modify your `.htaccess` file and add the following

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

This is a more detailed approach to your already working one.

**Important Note:** Google PageSpeed Insights will detect a lack of gzip compression if any third party resources are not served gziped. You may see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758003/gzip-compression-is-not-detected-by-pagespeed-insights-node-js).

Comment: this still does not solve my problem, google wants me to compress "http://example.com/"

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located ?

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above, the compression algorithm might be functioning properly. Google thought will not give you a "pass" if any third party resources are not gziped !

Comment: htaccess is located in the root folder, google is only complaining about "/"

Comment: I assume you are loading something remotely, check any scripts, css files, fonts, svgs that load on your homepage. Download any resources and serve them from your machine. I suggest you take a look at the output of your home page.

Comment: everything is compressed, I add a screencap

Comment: What is checkgzipcompression.com giving you for your website ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved, by using [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)
and enabling "Compress pages so they’re served more quickly to visitors"